# Migration from react-jsx to typescript-tsx react

Tags: typescript, webpack, reactjs, jsx

I want to migrate from `react-jsx` react to `typescript-tsx` react. As I have many files to convert I want to do it gradually. I want to keep old `react-jsx` file and for new features in my application I use typescript, then I will convert old `react-jsx` files to `tsx`. Is there any way to compile both `react-jsx` with `Babel` and `tsx` together in bundle file in `webpack`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is!  In your webpack config you just need to specify different loaders for *.jsx and *.tsx files.  In situations using both typescript and babel I tend to get typescript to preserve JSX, and output ES6 modules, then use Babel to deal with the JSX.  Your .tsconfig would be something like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "allowJs": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": [
            "dom", 
            "es7"
        ]
    }
}
```

And your webpack (assuming v2) loaders would be:

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    use: [{
        loader: "babel-loader",
    }],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
},
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
            loader: "ts-loader"
        }
    ]
}
```